# pyspark on windows (Upgrade from 1.6 to 2.0.2): sqlContext.read.format fails

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The following line works very well in 1.6 although fails in 2.0.2. Any idea, what could be the issue

```
file_name = "D:/ProgramFiles/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.3/data/mllib/sample_linear_regression_data.txt"
df_train = sqlContext.read.format("libsvm").load(file_name)
```

The error is

```
  File "<ipython-input-4-e5510d6d3d6a>", line 1, in <module>
    df_train = sqlContext.read.format("libsvm").load("../data/mllib/sample_linear_regression_data.txt")

  File "D:\ProgramFiles\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 147, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))

  File "D:\ProgramFiles\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)

  File "D:\ProgramFiles\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

IllegalArgumentException: 'Can not create a Path from an empty string'
```

Comment: is your path a local path ?

Comment: The issue persists with local path. Overall, On Window PySpark and Spark is very unstable. Looks like these are designed for Linux

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to this bug, that has since been corrected: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/11775

It raises this 'empty string' error instead of an invalid path.

You're using a relative path which will build a path from default directory that might have changed in your installation of spark2. Try setting environment variable `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` or specifying an absolute path instead of a relative one. If it's a local path use `file:///`

Comment: The issue persists with local path. Overall, On Window PySpark and Spark is very unstable. Looks like these are designed for Linux